# Xamarin binding jar couldn't load classes

Tags: android, jar, xamarin

I followed the steps [Binding a Jar Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/).However, once I complie the process ,hundreds of warning was shown to me ,most of it were "couldn't load class" warning. I don't know what should I do.

The version of Xamarin is 5.9.5(build 10).

I'm sorry I haven't enough reputation to post the image. I copied some warning messages here.

```
D:\project_c#\Android\OsmDroid\OsmDroid\JARTOXML: Warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class microsoft/mappoint/TileSystem : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: microsoft.mappoint.TileSystem (J2X9001) (OsmDroid)
D:\project_c#\Android\OsmDroid\OsmDroid\JARTOXML: Warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class net/wigle/wigleandroid/ZoomButtonsController$1 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.wigle.wigleandroid.ZoomButtonsController$1 (J2X9001) (OsmDroid)
D:\project_c#\Android\OsmDroid\OsmDroid\JARTOXML: Warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class net/wigle/wigleandroid/ZoomButtonsController$OnZoomListener : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.wigle.wigleandroid.ZoomButtonsController$OnZoomListener (J2X9001) (OsmDroid)
```

Comment: show us these warnings, dump the whole console output

Comment: I've posted some warning here @DeanWild

Comment: Are you trying to bind the osmdroid library? If so then it looks like one already exists http://components.xamarin.com/view/osmdroid-android-binding

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `$(AndroidClassParser)` MSBuild property to `class-parse`:

```
xbuild /p:AndroidClassParser=class-parse
```

or manually add the property to your `.csproj`
see - https://gist.github.com/prashantvc/09116d89ec5c8c4d4680d2b956862c0c#file-binding_sdkbase-csproj-L17